# Are HTML Meta Tags still important?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine, meta-tags

I read some articles on Internet, some said that search engine like Google and Bing don't care about HTML Meta Tags any more. Should I still need to maintain the HTML Meta Tags in my website properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did those sites you read that on have `META` tags?

Comment: Instead of reading "some articles on Internet", maybe you should have gone to Google directly: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812

Comment: I found that some websites have HTML Meta Tags, ex: Meta Description and Meta Keywords. Others don't have. I'm confusing.

Comment: Just read the Google SEO Guide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are meta tags critical? Every search engines emphasizes meta tags differently. Google doesn't let the public know how it uses meta tags. I have noticed that a lot of websites show up on the first page of Google for specific subjects and yet they don't have any keyword or description tags. So don't let anybody fool you by exaggerating how important they are for Search Engine Optimization. Search engines index algorithms vary greatly -- some assign a lot of importance to meta tags, so it is a good idea to use them.

Meta tags are lines of code that are hidden in web pages. The code information is not revealed in the web browser (but refer to the discussion of the description tag, below) but they are utilized by search engines to help categorize your web content. It is possible that you might choose to omit descriptions, or keywords, but your site won't look right if you don't put a "title" tag, since the web browsers will show it as "Untitled".

In order to obtain traffic (by cheating) a long time ago, people would place repetitive or irrelevant information into their meta tags -- "stuffing" them. As a penalty, several search engines don't put too much importance on keywords in meta tags, but they still look at them to be certain they have meaning. Whichever the case, your rank will probably suffer on other search engines if you lack meta tags, or have useless keywords.

The "head" section of a web page is where meta tags are found. Some people suggest using only lowercase letters in your tags, and avoid repeating terms within the keyword tag.

Generally speaking, the actual meta tag contents appear invisible; however the "description" meta tag's contents will turn up in the majority of search engines together with the page title in the search results. Do not overdo your meta description; you can place keywords in the description tag, but try to keep language natural, in complete sentences, and keep it short and relevant.

Comment: @_Google doesn't let the public know how it uses meta tags._     Actually it does so [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812)

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes - META tags are important.  But not all of them.

Purely from search engine listings - Always include a useful META DESCRIPTION thats unique for every page - even if that doesn't bump you up the rankings, a good succinct description will do wonders for your click throughs and bounce rates, because people are more likely to think they can find what they are looking for.

I would also include META KEYWORDS although it should be said that its probably of no use - so I generally pick out some site wide keywords and use them throughout.

Other META tags have uses such as the ROBOTS tag, and the like - but they are for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

here is the thing: what do you summarize as meta tags, do you only mean meta tags or everything in the

```
<head>
```

of your HTML? the sloppy definition of meta tags mostly includes these elements as well.

these "meta" tags are still very very important for efficient SEO.

`<title></title>` (not really a meta tag, but in the `<head>` section) because google uses it (in most cases) as the headline of the listing in the SERP

`<meta rel="description" content="because google uses this text here as the snippet text of the SERP (in most cases)` listing">

```
 <meta content='noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet' name='robots'/>
```

a very efficient directive to control the  indexing behavior (and to some extend the crawling behavior and value allocation)  of google

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”noodp”>
```

get rid of snippets that use http://www.dmoz.org/ for descriptions

```
  <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
```

advises google to not index the images found on this page (but they might get indexed if they are used on other pages)

```
<link href='http://www.example.com/en/vienna/cha-no-ma' rel='canonical' />
```

(not meta, but in the head) communicate a canonical  URL (the one you would like to get indexed) to the search engines.

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/en/vienna/b/billa" hreflang="en" rel="alternate" />
```

together with the canonical a cool way to communicate alternate language versions of a page to google

```
<link href='http://microformats.org/profile/hcard' rel='profile' />
```

if you want to achieve rich snippets in google by using microformats, these meta informations are necessary.

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

indication of content type and encoding

```
<META NAME="google-site-verification" CONTENT="+nxGUDJ4QpAZ5l9Bsjdi102tLVC21AIh5d1Nl23908vVuFHs34="/>
```

a way to verify your site for google webmaster tools

stuff that is not important:

meta keyword tag, just forget about it. its useless (and if you put spammy words in it even of negative value)