# Can somebody tell me the use of (nofollow & noimageindex) metatag in html?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Can somebody tell me the use of (nofollow & noimageindex)  metatag in html? Like, what do they specifically do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477808/are-html-meta-tags-still-important/5483333#5483333 Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow, noimageindex">`

This is just an information for crawling robots (like Google's one) that this page shouldn't be crawled. So it's not gonna be shown in Google search results.

`nofollow` means that this page shouldn't be followed by redirection from the other page. Let's say you have index.php which has:

`<a href='nofollowedpage.php'>link</a>` and `nofollowedpage.php` has meta with nofollow. So robot just click on that link but when it see meta with `nofollow` he will quit and forget about this site. It's working in similar way like :

`<a href='nofollowedpage.php' rel='nofollow'>link</a>`

`noimageindex` - This tag will prevent indexing images from your site or external site on that page.